# Java Process Not Able To Write Logs To Console

Tags: java, logging, stdout, log4j2

I am implementing log4j2 in my java application where I trying to write data to console using log4j2 configuration file. I have created a jar called Interface.jar .  Soft Links are created for this jar and are run with different arguments . 2 soft links created are Interface1 and Interface2 with different arguments . Interface1 and Interface2 have different log4j2  configuration file path.

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", System.getenv("LOG4J_INTERFACE1"));
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", System.getenv("LOG4J_INTERFACE2"));
```

Log4j Configuration File For Interface1 is :

```
status = warn
appenders=console
property.LOG_PATTERN = %d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz}|%p|INTERFACE1||||||%m%n
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = ${LOG_PATTERN}
logger.Log4JExample.name = Log4JExample
logger.Log4JExample.level = debug
logger.Log4JExample.additivity = false
logger.Log4JExample.appenderRef.console.ref = LogToConsole
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LogToConsole
```

Log4j Configuration File For Interface2 is :

```
status = warn
appenders=console
property.LOG_PATTERN = %d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz}|%p|INTERFACE2||||||%m%n
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = LogToConsole2
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = ${LOG_PATTERN}
logger.Log4JExample.name = Log4JExample
logger.Log4JExample.level = debug
logger.Log4JExample.additivity = false
logger.Log4JExample.appenderRef.console.ref = LogToConsole2
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LogToConsole2
```

The issue is that when I start both the process , Interface1 is able to write to console but Interface2 is not able to do so. Both the process are running fine. One challenge I see is that both these jars have save main class Interface.class .

```
 LogManager.getLogger(Interface.class);
```

Can anyone shed some light on how can I  stream the data to console from multiple processes using soft links.

Comment: Where is the softlink you mention? How do logging statements in your code look like? What is the full classname of your Interface?

Comment: Logging looks like this in Interface1 app:                                                                                   
     2023-01-13 13:59:35,147 CET|INFO|Interface1|||||| Connection Done  .              
  Full class name is  com/test/Interface.class

Comment: Need to have 2 different appenders

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are running the same application twice with different environment variables. In such a case just use the standard `LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE` environment variable (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)) or pass a `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=...` command line parameter.

Comment: @Ashok Did that too , created different appenders Console1 and Console2 . Still couldnt get it  to work

Comment: @Piotr You  are right . I have different set of command line arguments for Interfac1 and Interface2 which helps me identify which log4j file to use. But the solution you have recommended , how is it different from what I have used. System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", System.getenv("LOG4J_INTERFACE1")); . Shouldn't the above statement serve the same purpose.

Comment: Assuming you set the system property before any call to `LogManager` (these are usually in static initialization code, so run very early), your code will work but: 1. it's code, so changing the name of the environment variable requires recompiling, 2. it's useless, since environment variables can be used directly by Log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

Need to have 2 appenders. You can use give all the appenders with comma separated.

I can see both loggers have different format and both needs to write the console. In those cases you need to use Marker filter for different loggers.

below is the sample `log4j2.properties` file

```
appenders = console, console1

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz}|%p|INTERFACE1||||||%m%n

appender.console1.type = Console
appender.console1.name = LogToConsole2
appender.console1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console1.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz}|%p|INTERFACE2||||||%m%n

loggers = rolling, interface2
logger.rolling.name = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling


#configure rootLogger and attach all the appenders to it
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = LogToConsole

logger.interface2.name = Interface2
logger.interface2.additivity = false
logger.interface2.level = debug
logger.interface2.appenderRef.console1.ref = LogToConsole2
```

Comment: Hello Ashok.  The  classname is same  for both Interface1 and Interface2 . So we decided to go with 2 different log4j2 files and both these processes refer to their own log4j2 file . Interface1 uses log4j2_Interface1.property and Interface2 uses  log4j2_Interface2.property.  In this case we are getting the issue . If I understand it correctly ,what you are trying to do will work in case we have 2 different processes having different  class names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting a system property like so:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", System.getenv("LOG4J_INTERFACE1"));
```

while you should be setting `log4j2.configurationFile`.
Notice the log4j2 prefix.

I also recommend setting another system property

```
java -Dlog4j2.debug=true ...
```

just to see more what log4j2 is doing. You can turn it off once you are happy.